# Asus Rt-AC66U Firmware upgrade problems

Tags: router, wireless-router, wired-networking

I have a strange problem with my Asus RT-Ac66U Wireless Router , which I am using Wired to my Asus Rampage III Extreme motherboard...

The problem I have is that when I am trying to upgrade my firmware, it always fails... Well it takes about 30minutes before I cancel the process... I have tried using both IE, Edge, Chrome, Chromium, and also FireFox, which is my daiy driver...

So it has nothing to do with the browser I am using...

I had to resort to using the following:

https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1000814/

It worked, but the next time I will update the firmware, I have to use that method again, as it fails to update my firmware using the webui. Why is that, do I have a hardware error or is it some problem with my settings or what can it be?? It was quite strange that I got it to work using the 'emergency upgrade' method.

Comment: Why are you updating the firmware so often?  The OEM firmware I know isn't being Update that often on a 3 year old device

Comment: 380.62_HGG-FINAL (based on RMerlin 380.62)

Comment: Did you try the upgrade in compatibility mode for IE or chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem, as I didn't plug my wire into the LAN-1, but I was using the LAN-2 port on my router to plug in my computer...

But I haven't tested it yet...

Edit: I have now successfully upgraded to the latest firmware available for my